# Lee variable num_cars_item en el sandbox de PayPal

Tags: php, paypal

Alguien que haya probado sandbox de PayPal, lo que necesito saber cómo probar el envío de múltiples productos del carrito a la variable `num_cars_items`, y recibirlas en  la misma variable. Ya que cuando lo simulo en el sandbox poniendo varios items como productos, no los envía; y cuando pongo solo uno, sí me llega y los guarda en la base de datos.

```
$num_cars_item = $_post['num_cars_item'];
for($i=1;$i<=num_cars_item;$i++){
  $item.$i
}
```

En teoría esto funciona pero no recibo nada en la varible `car_item`. ¿Alguien sabe cómo probar la pasarela con varios items?

Comment: Hola, el código compartido es algo raro. Estás leyendo de `$_post` pero debería ser `$_POST`, además la parte de `$item.$i` no termina de quedar clar. ¿Qué es lo que estás intentando hacer exactamente?

Comment: Hola alvaro montoro, lo que sucede es que intento probar paypal para el carrito de compras con rl simulador de paypal de respuesta, para verificar que se completo el pago,  funciona con un producto, pero cuando intento enviar dos productos no tengo resultado, ya que las variable num_cars_item me devuelve cero,  ya que necesito que me devuelva un resultado mayor a cero para que las demas variables que esten dentro del for me devuelvan algo en su posicion $i.

Answer (score 0):

No se a que te refieres, estas tratando en tu ejemplo la respuesta de paypal, o estás tratando de enviarle la información a paypal? si es enviarla es en los input number_item.$i desde el 1 hasta el que tengas y si es recibirla tendrias que hacer un foreach para recibir los datos de laa variable, que seria $_POST['item_number1'] $_POST['item_number2'] $_POST['item_number3'] etc, en el 1 2 3 ahi va $i porque recuerda que estás dentro del foreach recibiendo los datos. pero no sabemos cuantos items se compraron.

Comment: Hola pregunton_de_desarrollo_web, gracias por responder, lo que sucede es que no encuentro como hacer que el simulador de paypal me envie varios productos, las variables con un solo item si las envia bien pero cuando le doy mas item , la variable $num_cars_item; no me envia nada,  y no puedo checar como funciona el for para insertar a la base de datos. Mi problema es mas bien con el sandbox y no con el codigo,  si alguien ha podido enviar varios articulos del sandbox a su pagina de respuesta y cacharlo con la variable $num_cars_item;